# Cannot access laravel-websockets dashboard on xampp-vm

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, xampp-vm

I'm trying to run `laravel-websockets` on XAMPP-VM, however, I cannot access `localhost:6001/laravel-websockets` debugging dashboard after running `php artisan websockets:serve`.

Inside the console I am getting `Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...` which sort of indicates that the server is running.

In XAMPP-VM config, I did define port forwarding as `*:6001 -> 6001 (Over SSH)` (Did try other ports `6002 -> 6001 (Over SSH)`, still no luck.).

If anyone could direct me in a right direction or point out what I am doing wrong, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution in my case was following:

`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,` was commented out inside `config\app.php`.

Secondly, the url for it was `localhost:8080/laravel-websockets`

Answer (score 0):

you need to run both commands `php artisan websockets:serve` and `php artisan serve`
run first one in your editors terminal and then run second command by opening cmd.

after that, access your dashboar using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/laravel-websockets`